# LoadImage failed in 8 bit image

Tags: windows, winapi, gdi

I have problem with this code, when I load 8 bit BMP file.

```
HBITMAP hbm = LoadImageW(NULL, L"C:\\Test.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
```

But **HBITMAP** is 0 and **GetLastError** also returns 0.

Where is the problem ?

I see similar questions on stackoverflow, but this code only failed in 8 bit bitmaps.

MSDN say nothing about this behavior.

Thanks for answer or any suggestion.

***EDIT: Same bitmap loaded as resource work fine**.*

***Operating system: Windows XP SP2***

***EDIT 2: I tested opening this image yesterday with Photoshop - fine, MSPAINT - fine, Microsoft Agent Character Editor - failed, my app - failed! Tested today - now works!!! Tested again 10 minutes ago - do not work. Probably some kind of lock? I found similar question: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/vcmfcatl/thread/df4aa858-6d59-402d-8d96-6414774fed31**.*

Comment: Do you know that you're missing a backslash from the path?  It should be `L"C:\\Test.bmp"`.

Comment: Try adding `LR_CREATEDIBSECTION` flag, maybe device-dependent bitmap can not contain that 8-bit bmp on your machine. I don't know why last error is 0 though.

Comment: Missing backslash is typing error :-). Also if this was problem GetLastError returns 2 not 0. :-)

Comment: What about putting the file into a different directory, which is not subject to virtualization/redirection?

Comment: Maybe a... licensing issue! The code looks very much OK. Is the bitmap run-lenght compressed or it is uncompressed? Try saving it as uncompressed (prederably with all 256 palette entries). If this works then it's indeed a licensing issue.

Comment: Hello. The bitmap is uncompressed. Also changing directory bring same result.

Comment: Can you post the bitmap at some file (not image!) exchange service to take a look? Sounds quite challenging though basic! Also what OS are you running it under?

Comment: The code snippet is workable. It at least works on some systems, so it appears that your description is incomplete and you are missing important information: the bitmap file, OS version, relevant system settings.

Comment: Now edit question, I don not understand what the hell is it. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I found what caused problem.

Problem was incorrect set *biSizeImage* member of the *BITMAPINFOHEADER*.

But after unsleeped night when I tested two images (80x80, 128x128), I found interesting things.

*LoadImage* still successfully load image with incorrect *biSizeImage* from **0** to **real size + 1052**. For example for 80x80 image, *biSizeImage* must be 6400, but *LoadImage* loads image with *biSizeImage* set to 0 or 1, or 6401, or 6402...but failed after setting 7453.

Still remains question, why *LoadImage* successed load image from resource with any *biSizeImage* value.

Answer (score 1):

Try using GDI+ instead. It has much more functionality for image manipulation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms535411(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I know GDI+, but I dont ask question about GDI+. :-)

Comment: Sure, I understand that but sometimes it's best to move onto to something that works rather than wasting time on something that doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Since the file is in `C:\`, maybe you don't have permission to access it?  Try putting it on the desktop or My Documents instead.

Also, updating to XP SP3 won't hurt.

Comment: No, in this situation,GetLastError returns ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.